# Javascript Print() sometimes firing print layout/paper size options and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

This is the exact same function I am using in two different parts of my application. (Which is an Ember application). However, in the first instance, when you fire this function, the application opens a new window with the html data on it, then opens a print dialog with the options layout and paper size.

In the second instance, these options are not included. Why would this happen? Or, if there is a better way to format for printing, what am I doing wrong?

```
printPreview: function() { //For Printing Issue Document
    var data = $('#editDoc').editable('getHTML', false, true);
    data = '<div class="froala-view">' + data + '</div>';
    data = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/froala_editor.css">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/froala_content.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/froala_style.css">' + data;
    // debugger


    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=825,height=590');
    printWindow.document.write(data);
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function() { //content loaded after 1 sec print will invoke
        printWindow.print();
    }, 1000);

},
```

Comment: Where do you invoke it and how?

Comment: It's an Ember Action in the controller, fired when on the click of a button.

Comment: In both cases? And the difference is stable, depending on which button/action you click? What are other differences between two cases?

Comment: Yessir. This exact block of code, letter for letter for both actions. Both actions are even called the same; they're just on different controllers. 

Also interesting thing: it only happens with Chrome. Safari and Firefox both go directly into the printer dialog, whereas Chrome's print dialog shows up as an intermediate.

Comment: No idea, man. :( Try finding further differences, try debugging by imitating the conditions of one situation in the other and vice versa. I hate this kind of bugs. Luckily yours isn't a critical one.